# Is there a way to animate the HERE API marker to move more smootly from position A to B on the map?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I need to animate the marker when moving from position A to B. It could be a slide for example.

I was using marker.setPosition but it does not have any parameter to set the animation.

```
marker.setPosition({ lat: number; lng: number });
```

As I am working on a project to let the passenger follow the bus moving on the map, it does not have a good user experience to simply set the new position of the bus. I expect the marker to move more smoothly from position A to B.

Comment: Hi, there is an example for animating a marker using setTimeout() method. Pleas see this link: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/geofencing. Would you please take a look at it?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport 
This is not exactly what I was looking for, in that example it is clearly not making any animation. As I mentioned, I expect to see some kind of smooth movement when changing the marker position on the map.

Answer (score 0):

The examples using setTimeout() in tcs.ext.here.com.
Also you can customize the example using setInterval() function.
Please see below a simple code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,
      width=device-width" />
          <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
#myAnimation {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px;position: relative;" id="mapContainer">
</div>
 <div id ="myAnimation"></div>

<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': 'APIKEY'
});

// Get the default map types from the Platform object:
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

  // Instantiate the map:
var map = new H.Map(
  document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
  {
    zoom: 15,
    center: { lng: 13.8, lat: 52.3 }
  });
</script>

<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button> 
</body>
</html>
```